# Overriding liferay core interface

Tags: interface, overriding, liferay

Is there any way to override liferays core interface, for example com.liferay.portal.model.Plugin ?

I tried already overriding classes, but have some problems with interfaces. I've created new "ext" plugin, and put package com.liferay.portal.model in both:

docroot/WEB-INF/ext-impl/src
and
docroot/WEB-INF/ext-service/src

and of course put in that package interface Plugin.

To test overriding ive added to method declaration

public void test();

but Plugin interface doesnt get overriden.

What i did worked with class, but i cannot make those damn interfaces working.

Is there any way to acomplish what im trying to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating an upgrade nightmare for yourself if you change the core interfaces - most likely you'll have huge problems every time you upgrade. And your sample (adding public void test()) doesn't hint that there's a real usecase for this.

I assume that it'll be a lot simpler to just add your interface/feature/functionality in new classes or to add your functionality in other plugins until you give proper usecases. Once you provide these, we can actually start talking about proper solutions for them. And, most likely, they don't involve messing with the internal interfaces of Liferay's implementation.

Comment: Yea, im aware this is generally bad to override interfaces, ive read alot about it, but i was asked to test if its possible, i have no idea why, but if its possible, id like to try it.

Comment: The pragmatist's answer is: Technically it's possible, but it will generate so much of an upgrade nightmare that it's not worth going that route. Sprinkle in stronger language as politically appropriate - if you run into issues after you do such a thing, nobody will like to help you as nobody has an idea what's going on. If you use 3rd party applications from the marketplace, they might not run due to interface mismatches.